# Leaflet panTo (focus map by coordinates)

Tags: leaflet

How can I panTo() not by center coordinates, but by edge coordinates (set min and max latlon). I very need in it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use map.fitBounds

```
var southWest = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227),
northEast = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125),
bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-fitbounds

Comment: What do you mean by the correct zoom?  The zoom level should correspond with the bounds of your visible map.